# rails console find model's parent if exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model named Vehicle. How do I find what the parent of Vehicle is through the rails console i.e.

```
vehicle = Vehicle.find(1)
vehicle.parent
vehicle.parent_id.present?
```

Comment: What do the relations (belongs_to, has_many) look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"parent" is for classes only, not instances. So, for class parent

```
vehicle.class.parent
```

If you mean **associations** instead of class, use `reflections`

```
vehicle.reflections
```